# Clearing map layers with react-leaflet and hooks

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-hooks, react-leaflet

I'm building a custom plugin for `react-leaflet` to locate the user using leaflet's [locate](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-locate) method.

It works basically, but with the one problem of the layer not clearing between turning location off and back on again. Each time the locate button is toggled, `locate` should start fresh.

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-problem-not-clearing-layers-on-locate-vvyrj) of the problem. As you toggle the button, the circle becomes darker as the layers are stacked on top of each other.

Here is the component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'
import L from 'leaflet'
import { useLeaflet } from 'react-leaflet'
import LocationSearchingIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LocationSearching';
import MapButton from './MapButton'

function Locate() {

  const { map } = useLeaflet();

  const [locate, setLocate] = useState(false);

  function toggleLocate() {
    setLocate(!locate)
  }

  console.log(locate)

  const layerRef = useRef(L.layerGroup());

  useEffect(() => {

    if (locate) {
      map.removeLayer(layerRef.current)
      map.locate({ setView: false, watch: true, enableHighAccuracy: true }) /* This will return map so you can do chaining */
        .on('locationfound', function (e) {
          L.circleMarker([e.latitude, e.longitude], {
            radius: 10,
            weight: 3,
            color: 'white',
            fillColor: 'blue',
            fillOpacity: 1
          }).addTo(layerRef.current);
          L.circle([e.latitude, e.longitude], e.accuracy / 2, {
            weight: 1,
            color: 'blue',
            fillColor: 'blue',
            fillOpacity: 0.2
          }).addTo(layerRef.current);
          window.localStorage.setItem('accuracy', e.accuracy)
          map.setView([e.latitude, e.longitude], 16)
          layerRef.current.addTo(map)
        })
        .on('locationerror', function (e) {
          alert("Location error or access denied.");
        })
    } if (!locate) {
      map.stopLocate();
      map.removeLayer(layerRef.current);
    }
  }, [locate, map]);

  return (
    <MapButton
      title={locate ? 'Click to disable location' : 'Click to locate'}
      onClick={toggleLocate}
      left
      top={102}
    >
      <LocationSearchingIcon fontSize="small" style={{ color: locate ? 'orange' : '' }} />
    </MapButton>
  )
}

export default Locate
```

I would appreciate any solution or tips to stop the layers stacking, and clear properly went the button is toggled. Thanks

Comment: Add the circle to a featureGroup and then every time `locationfound` is fired, you call `featuregroup.clearLayers()` and then add the circle new to the featureGroup

Comment: @FalkeDesign thank you, this solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

As Falke Design's [mentions in a comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60989141/clearing-map-layers-with-react-leaflet-and-hooks/60990807#comment107902023_60989141):

> Add the circle to a featureGroup and then every time `locationfound` is fired, you call `featuregroup.clearLayers()` and then add the circle new to the featureGroup

This solved the problem.

The working codesandbox is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fixed-react-leaflet-problem-not-clearing-layers-on-locate-qn9wp)